# Google Maps Json to GPX

Tags: javascript, maps, timeline

I'm trying to get the coordinates from google timeline to convert them into gpx format. Do there exist an Api to which can extract time and location from the google maps timeline json out?

The json-file looks like this:

```
{
  "locations" : [{
    "timestampMs" : "1383767355903",
    "latitudeE7" : 481848021,
    "longitudeE7" : 112554011,
    "accuracy" : 100
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1383767295887",
    "latitudeE7" : 481848003,
    "longitudeE7" : 112554027,
    "accuracy" : 100
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have coordinates in google pixels and you need to convert this coordinate to latlong.

```
function latLng2Point(latLng, map) {
  var topRight = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
  var bottomLeft = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
  var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
  var worldPoint = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
  return new google.maps.Point((worldPoint.x - bottomLeft.x) * scale, (worldPoint.y - topRight.y) * scale);
}

function point2LatLng(point, map) {
  var topRight = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
  var bottomLeft = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
  var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
  var worldPoint = new google.maps.Point(point.x / scale + bottomLeft.x, point.y / scale + topRight.y);
  return map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldPoint);
}
```